# Are there any deep learning techniques to use the content of an image for another image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, reference-request, image-processing

Are there any machine learning or deep learning techniques to use the content of an image for another image?

More specifically, suppose I take a photo of a notebook. I get the angle, lighting, and perspective perfect. Now I copy an image I found online that contains text or handwriting. Is there a machine learning technique that would now draw this writing in my notebook?

Just asking if it's possible before I attempt to hire someone.

Comment: What do you mean by "draw this writing on my notebook"? Do you mean a computer physically drawing/painting an image onto a piece of paper?

Comment: Is your goal *only* to repoduce "flat" images of text/drawings/photos in situ in placeholder images with existing or blank pages? What is the scale of number of placeholder images (the perfect shots of notebooks) and number of content images (the text/handwriting)?